# manager tag is horrible, I have killed it

Tags: discussion, tags

I ran into [manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/manager) and realized that people weren't really using it properly, instead it was people doing things like [network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/network) and [manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/manager) instead of just [network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/network-manager).

Ditto for file-manager, modem-manager, power-manager, and so on.

So I redited the questions to get rid of it, but I thought I'd post it here as it might be a good idea to blacklist it to force the questions into the right tags instead of allowing "manager" to exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!

If it keeps re-appearing, let us know and we can consider actually blacklisting it.